# Xamarin android push notification OnMessageReceived() event is not calling when app is on background or killed mode

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin forms application and I implemented push notification on it. I want to navigate to different pages when user taps on the push notification depends on the notification data. So for that doing some codes in  `OnMessageReceived` event and it's working as expected if app is open mode. But this event is not triggering on other modes, please help me on this.
I refer this link to implement push notification ,[pushnotification on xamarin forms](https://heartbeat.comet.ml/firebase-cloud-messaging-for-remote-push-notifications-on-android-with-xamarin-3c72fffcd25).

Here is my json payload for android.

```
{
  "notification": 
           { "title" : "Sample App", "body" : "New items are available"},
  "data" : 
        {"Id" : "876df123", "pageName" : "ClothingsPage" } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the notification payload to the below format, after that it worked.

`{"data" : {"Id" : "123456", "body" : " test mobile app", "title" :  "SampleTest" } }`

Answer (score 0):

At first, there was an existed issue on the github which is about [Xamarin.Forms Android Pushnotification FCM OnMessageReceived not fired when app is background](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1968). And [the comment in it](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1968#issuecomment-368110619) explains the cause.

In addition, there is an open issue about the [push notification when app is closed](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/273). And you can try the accepted answer in this case which is about the [FCM messages unable to be handled when app is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68089803/17455524).

Generally speaking, it seems the cause is the limit of the push notification in the xamarin's android platform. You can check the [official document about the firebase message service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows#implement-firebasemessagingservice).